# Python JIRA - Timeouts?

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I'm attempting to use the Python JIRA module (http://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) within a Flask app and I'm struggling to raise errors on long loads/retries that can occur if the JIRA server is unavailable. I've tried both the timeout and max_retries settings noted in the API docs to no avail.

Has anyone had success raising an error if JIRA happens to be unavailable when a method relying on it is called?

Comment: I've caught the error turned it off with `max_retries=0`